# failed to open stream: HTTP wrapper does not support writeable connections in Wp-Content(0755)

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm writing a php script to watermark an exiting image in wordpress.
But I get "HTTP wrapper does not support writeable connections in Wp-Content"
Since it has 0755 permission mode.

imagejpeg($img_after_watermark, 'http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/new_img.jpg');

Is there a way i can save this image to my wordpress upload directory without changing the wp-content's permission mode?

Comment: I wonder how wordpress image watermark plugins duplicate an image and save to wp-content folder. Any reply would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: you should pass a path instead of a uri, your server is set not to allow http connections for server operations as it should be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just answering my own question incase someone comes looking for it.

Needed to pass path instead of Url.

/wp-content/uploads/2016/new_img.jpg

Worked like a charm!